# Rails views with components/partials using separate controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a Rails view with multiple components that use separate controllers, similar to how a Vue or React app has components with different data sources on the same page.

I've looked closely at rails partials and ViewCompoents (https://viewcomponent.org/), but nether seems suitable.

I'll use a book publishing website on the books.com/index page as an example.

1. header and body come from the layout.
2. blue block on the left is a "list of publishers" using the publisher's controller.
3. pink block on the right is a "list of books" using the books controller.

I'm still junior Rails dev so please don't flame me if this is an obvious question, but I can't find any examples of how to do this. Maybe my understanding of a controller is flawed because I'm used to thinking about 1 controller with 1 model...

Any help or links to resources would be appreciated!

[image: example website]

Comment: it is possible, but not conventional, to render a page from multiple controllers. There is no reason to restrict a controller to handling a single model, this limitation is a misunderstanding. It would be better to populate books and publishers from a single controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for here is [Turbo Frames](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames). If you're using Rails 7 this will already be installed and ready for you to use.

Set up a Turbo Frame for each of your sections and have the `src` element point to the route you want and that controller will be responsible for populating the frame.